# How to get the address of the buffer in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffi

So the quesion, I want to pass a pointer to a buffer I created in JS to a C++ library. How to get the address of a buffer in memory?

Comment: This would be unsafe. Instead, you'd use a [worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker) and [transfer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Transferable_objects) the underlying buffer or use a [shared buffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not superfamiliar with `ffi`, but it looks like `Buffer` instances are passed around by reference automatically (I'm using `ffi-napi` because `ffi` didn't want to install on macOS):

```
// C code
#include <stdio.h>

void show_my_buffer(void* buffer) {
  printf("Buffer: %s\n", (const char*) buffer);
}

// JS code
const ffi = require('ffi-napi');

const libmylibrary = ffi.Library('libmylibrary', {
  'show_my_buffer': [ 'void', [ 'void *' ] ]
});

const buffer = Buffer.from('hello world');
libmylibrary.show_my_buffer(buffer);
```

(And yes, I'm treating a buffer as if it were a string, which it isn't)